# React Native - FlatList Not Render TO Binding Another Componet

Tags: mysql, react-native, fetch-api

[image: FlatListRenderFails]
here some error in flatlist rendering time the following details are describe in this image. please help me for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following code

```
if(!dataSource) {
  return null;
}
```

Change your `renderItem` like

```
renderItem={ ({ item, index }) => {
  return ...
}}
```

Comment: Sorry Sir Its Not Worked